# Nginx redirect from http to https is stuck

Tags: nginx

I'm deploying a Rails application on personal server using Nginx, phusion_passenger. I've site configuration file with following server blocks. With this configuration my https://192.168.1.121 service works but my connection doesn't redirect from http://192.168.1.121. What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate any help, please.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        #server_name 192.168.1.121;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        listen 443 ssl default;

        #server_name 192.168.1.121;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com

        # Certificate details
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;

        root /home/deploy/www/myapplication/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

semi-colon is missing at end of server_name variable for http as well as https:

```
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
```

Comment: Missing ";" was a typo but my actual config file doesn't have missing ";".